# Help to design this TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Any ideas how can I achieve this as posted in the picture? [image]

from the three controls in the picture - ignore labels- , the button is fixed meaning that it does not resize but the other two are resizing when I am resizing their form - the same thing ANCHOR does -

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how I did it. let me know if you know how to do it in a better way:

- a 2X2 table layout
- the combobox should be anchored to left-top-right and ALSO its columnSpan property set to 2
- at cell[1,1] : put that text box.. anchor: left-top-right
- at cell[1,2] : put that button BUT set its DOCK to the RIGHT
- in the row/col editor set column 1 to take 90% and column 2 to take 10%

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a TableLayout Panel. Just do this

- Anchor **TextBox** to **Left, Right and Top**
- Anchor **DropDown** to **Left, Right and Top**
- Anchor **Button** to **Right and Top**

Comment: cannot use Anchor in this question.. otherwisr the textbox will overlap the button when resizing.

Comment: you can. Follow the instruction I posted. Just make sure to anchor button to top right.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Use two TableLayoutPanels (which I prefer) one with five rows and one column (one spacer row with fixed height) above "Optional case step" label, another nested with one row and two columns.
2. Just as you finally did.